# How do I display the list in a navBar when you click on the hamburger menu? Specifically the 'home' and 'about' 'text

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
Below is my html/css. Feel free to see how it looks in your ide(I use vscode). When I click on the hamburger menu in the shrunken screen I want the 'Home' and 'About' text in the nav to appear and stack on top of eachother. I'm really just struggling with the JS(making the text appear once you click on the hamburger menu), I can try to implement the stacking afterwards but if you want to give it a shot go right ahead. Anything will help, and if you can implement the menu with JS that'll be amazing, that's what I've been trying to get down through this project. good day.
Below is my html/css. Feel free to see how it looks in your ide(I use vscode). When I click on the hamburger menu in the shrunken screen I want the 'Home' and 'About' text in the nav to appear and stack on top of eachother. I'm really just struggling with the JS(making the text appear once you click on the hamburger menu), I can try to implement the stacking afterwards but if you want to give it a shot go right ahead. Anything will help, and if you can implement the menu with JS that'll be amazing, that's what I've been trying to get down through this project. good day.
```

Below is my html/css. Feel free to see how it looks in your ide(I use vscode). When I click on the hamburger menu in the shrunken screen I want the 'Home' and 'About' text in the nav to appear and stack on top of eachother. I'm really just struggling with the JS(making the text appear once you click on the hamburger menu), I can try to implement the stacking afterwards but if you want to give it a shot go right ahead. Anything will help, and if you can implement the menu with JS that'll be amazing, that's what I've been trying to get down through this project. good day.

```
'''''''
html
'''''''

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <title>Backroads || Tour Company</title>
            <!-- favicon -->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
            <!-- font-awesome -->
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="./fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/all.min.css"
            />
            <link rel=”stylesheet” href=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css”>
            <!-- styles css -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
          </head>
        
          <body>
            <!-- header  -->
            <main>
        <nav class="topNav">
          <ul>
            <div>
              <li><img src="./images/favicon.ico" alt=""></li>
            </div>
            <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="showText()">
              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-title">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </main>
<!-- js -->
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
        
'''''''
css
'''''''
        
        /*
        =============== 
        Fonts
        ===============
        */
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap");
        
        /*
        =============== 
        Variables
        ===============
        */
        
        :root {
          /* primary/main color */
          --clr-primary-5: hsl(185, 62%, 45%);
          --clr-white: #fff;
          --transition: all 0.3s linear;
          --spacing: 0.25rem;
          --ff-primary: "Lato", sans-serif;
        }
        /*
        =============== 
        Global Styles
        ===============
        */
        
        * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
          font-family: var(--ff-primary);
          background: var(--clr-white);
          color: var(--clr-grey-1);
          line-height: 1.5;
          font-size: 0.875rem;
        }
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
        a {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        img {
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
        }
        
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4 {
          letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
          text-transform: capitalize;
          line-height: 1.25;
          margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 3rem;
        }
        h2 {
          font-size: 2rem;
        }
        h3 {
          font-size: 1.25rem;
        }
        h4 {
          font-size: 0.875rem;
        }
        p {
          margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
          color: var(--clr-grey-5);
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
          h1 {
            font-size: 4rem;
          }
          h2 {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
          }
          h3 {
            font-size: 1.75rem;
          }
          h4 {
            font-size: 1rem;
          }
          body {
            font-size: 1rem;
          }
          h1,
          h2,
          h3,
          h4 {
            line-height: 1;
          }
        }
        /*  global classes */
        
        .btn {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          background: var(--clr-primary-5);
          color: var(--clr-white);
          padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
          letter-spacing: var(--spacing);
          display: inline-block;
          transition: var(--transition);
          font-size: 0.875rem;
          border: 2px solid transparent;
          cursor: pointer;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        .btn:hover {
          color: var(--clr-primary-1);
          background: var(--clr-primary-8);
        }
        
        /* 
        =============== 
        Navbar
        =============== */
        
        /* background of navbar */
        nav ul{
        background-color: grey;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: .5rem;
        border: white solid;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        }
        
        nav ul li {
          padding: 0 .5rem;
        }
        
        /* icon image */
         nav div{
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        nav div li img  {
          width: 2rem;
        }
        
        .hamburger{
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 20px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        
        nav li a{
          color: var(--clr-primary-5);
        }
        
        .hamburger:focus{
          outline: none;
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          nav li a {
            display: none;
          }
        
          .hamburger{
            visibility: visible;
          }
        
      }
```

Comment: possible to include a working snippet?

Comment: Hi Justin, here are more solutions than you could have bargained for: [Codepen search: hamburger menu](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=hamburger+menu), with and without the use of Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

You can't put div as a child element of ul tag. You have to put li tag as a child of ul tag, then you can use div or a tag and whatever you want inside the li tag. And here I have used bootstrap 5.2 cdn and also font-awesome 6.1.1 cdn.
See the code below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("hide-ul");
}
```

```css
.topNav {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00ffd729;
}

.topul {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 800ms;
}

.hide-ul {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: all 800ms;
}

.topul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 800ms;
}

.hamburger {
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="topNav">
        <div  class="topul" id="myDIV" >
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="#section-title">About</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                     <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                     <a href="#section-title">About</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
      <a href="#"  class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="myFunction()">
           <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Care to add some explanations to your code to say how / why / where you have done what you have done?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).